# Stay on same tab after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a jQuery website that has a top menu to navigate through div's.  And i want it to stay on same tab that it was before refresh page.

**Menu Code**

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li class="menu-text"><h4>Title</h4></li> 
    <li class="current"><a href="#1" data-id="div1">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-id="div2">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-id="div3">Menu3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Content Div's**

```
<div class="pbox" id="div1"> ... </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2"> ... </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3"> ... </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var menu = $('#menu');
menu.on('click', 'a', function () {
  var current = $(this).closest('li');
  if(!current.hasClass("current")){        
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    current.addClass("current");

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');       
    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
    $('#' + id + '.pbox').show(600);
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
  }
});

var menuId = location.hash.substring(1);
if (menuId) {
  $(menu, "li a[data-id='" + menuId + "']").trigger('click');
}
```

The only problem is that when i refresh the page the **URL** still the same (if i was on second tab and i refresh the page, the link will be: index.php#2) but 'redirect' to first tab (**#1**).

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can put a query parameter in the URL to make it easy for you to
  understand which was the last active tab.
- Another options is to use localStorage to save which is the last clicked tab and to receive it from the storage upon page/widget load

First one is simpler and covered here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

```
function myFunction() {
    location.hash = "part5";
    var x = "The anchor part is now: " + location.hash;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Second one you can find here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
Local storage way:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Martin. If i use the first method i can set it to be like `localStorage.setItem('lastDiv', menuId);` ?  I never used that method but it looks like what i want. After i set it i need to get it right? Can i use the method `localStorage.getItem`?

Comment: I saw that Martin. But i my problem is not retrieve the URL #. My problem is that the website must go to last tab the user was before refreshing the page. If you saw my jQuery code, you would notice that i already acomplish that by doing `var menuId = location.hash.substring(1)`. It is already storing the last tab visited.

Comment: Sorry mate, missed that one - so you should do it with localStorage then.

Comment: Do `localStorage` permite me to navigate to last tab visited by user?

Comment: Yes, store the tab in the storage, on page load, try to get it from it, if you have a value -> set the value on the tabs.

Comment: I want to **select** the tab not change values.

Comment: Yes, trigger the proper action once you retrieve which tab you want active. Upon refresh or navigate, you need to sniff out either localStorage or the URL to understand you need to open another tab. Then just init the same action you do on click to open this tab once again.